# Can't send file using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, form-data

The code is simple and it works when I append a string to the FormData:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('String', stringVar);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
request.send(data);
```

But if I append a file to the FormData (`data.append('File', fileVar);`) I get a 503 response.

The problem doesn't happen when I'm running the code on localhost, so I know there's no problem with the code and it's from the server. Maybe I should change some PHP or Apache settings on the server, I don't know.

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to check your service signature, 503 is service unavailable. Either your server is not reachable or this service is not available

Comment: How large is your files? Have you checked your Apache error log?

Comment: @gurvinder372 well the server is reachable. I can send string data with this method, just can't send a file. can you explain checking the service signature a little bit? I just did a quick google search and didn't find anything.

Comment: @slbteam08 it's about 60kb. Yes I checked it, but couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: `can you explain checking the service signature a little bit?` I meant that is your service capable of receiving a JSON object and marshal it into a PHP object?

Comment: @gurvinder372 well I think so, because sending a string as data works without any problems.

Comment: maybe then you can simply try `request.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: just found out accidentally that the problem's not happening if I'm connected to a vpn and my ip address is changed! The server accepted string data from the previous ip but not a file... very weird!